# IOS7 moving UIView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, ios7

I have a UIView defined in Interface Builder.

I need to nudge it down if the screenSize is 568.

I can not figure out auto layout.  My screen has:

nudgeView
iADbanner
TabBar

I have my IBOutlet set to nudgeView and figured I could nudge it.
So in my viewDidLoad, I am thinking of something like

```
if(iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 568){
    [nudgeView setFrameY: 40]; //no idea what this line should look like
}
```

which should just move that view down.

iAd and TabBar are aligned to bottom and do the right thing.

So any tips on how I can change the Y on the nudgeView?

Thanks,

Ian

Comment: See Andrey's answer, unless you are using auto layout. If you are using autolayout you are going to have to modify the constraints programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 568){

  CGRect frame = nudgeView.frame;
  frame.origin.y = 40;
  nudgeView.frame = frame;
 }
```

Comment: That looks like it thank you.  40 was too small, but now it does what I had hoped for.  Thank you very much, I appreciate it.  Ian